# La rotación en el plugin JQuery Fortune no se mantiene

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una prueba de rotación que pueden ver en el siguiente enlace: http://fortune.presentatenlaweb.com.ve/. Y estoy usando este plugin https://github.com/tehsis/jfortune.

Explico el problema: Supongamos que la primera vez que presionamos "Spin" la ruleta finaliza y cae el número 36 -abajo de las imágenes se puede ver en texto normal el valor que cae-, entonces nos fijamos la ubicación del 36 en ese momento. Volvemos a hacer girar la ruleta y esta vez cae el 2, deberíamos ir hasta el mismo lugar donde estaba el 36 para ver que ahí está el 2 ahora, pero no esta. Entonces ese es el problema, que la ruleta ni siquiera apunta siempre al lugar donde se supone esta la opción que es seleccionada al finalizar de girar y es esto necesario para poder ajustarla a la aguja que señala la opción.

Se puede ver 3 ejemplos que si funcionan correctamente, los enlaces están en el repositorio del plugin.

No sé si tenga algo mal o sea un error del plugin, ya pregunte en las issues del repositorio también. Espero que puedan ayudarme con esto.

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.board {
  position: relative;  
  width: 1280px;
  height: 720px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('board.jpg');
}

.roulette {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  left: 565px;
  top: 84px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('roulette.jpg');
  border-radius: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="board"></div>
    <div class="roulette">
    </div>
    <button class="spinner"><span>Spin!</span><div class="pointer"></div></button>
</div>
<div class="price">
</div>
```

Este es el código javascript que da vida a la ruleta:

```
var animals = [
    { animal : "Hormiga",   number: 36},
    { animal : "Gato",      number: 11},
    { animal : "Caiman",    number: 30},
    { animal : "Raton",     number: 8},
    { animal : "Cebra",     number: 23},
    { animal : "Tigre",     number: 10},
    { animal : "Leon",      number: 5},
    { animal : "Iguana",    number: 24},
    { animal : "Oso",       number: 16},
    { animal : "Panda",     number: 33},
    { animal : "Carnero",   number: 1},
    { animal : "Puerco",    number: 20},
    { animal : "Paloma",    number: 14},
    { animal : "Lapa",      number: 31},
    { animal : "Aguila",    number: 9},
    { animal : "Camello",   number: 22},
    { animal : "Burro",     number: 18},
    { animal : "Elefante",  number: 29},
    { animal : "Loro",      number: 7},
    { animal : "Zamuro",    number: 28},
    { animal : "Caballo",   number: 12},
    { animal : "Tiburon",   number: 35},
    { animal : "Cienpies",  number: 3},
    { animal : "Vaca",      number: 26},
    { animal : "Murcielago", number: 32},
    { animal : "Zorro",     number: 15},
    { animal : "Cabra",     number: 19},
    { animal : "Alacran",   number: 4},
    { animal : "Gallo",     number: 21},
    { animal : "Toro",      number: 2},
    { animal : "Gallina",   number: 25},
    { animal : "Pavo",      number: 17},
    { animal : "Pulpo",     number: 34},
    { animal : "Sapo",      number: 6},
    { animal : "Perro",     number: 27},
    { animal : "Mono",      number: 13}
];

var options = {};
options.prices = animals;
options.clockWise = false;
options.duration = 10000;
options.separation = 100;               

$(function() {
    var $r = $('.roulette')
    .fortune(options);
    var clickHandler = function() {
        $('.spinner').off('click');
        $('.spinner span').hide();
        $r.spin().done(function(win) {
            $('.price').text('Animal: ' + win.animal + ' and Number: ' + win.number);
            $('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
            $('.spinner span').show();
        });
    };

    $('.spinner').on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Siendo un código de un tercero, las opciones son pedirle soporte al desarrollador o, en todo caso, mostrar el fragmento de código específico que esté fallando. De la forma que está planteada la pregunta, no hay problema para solucionar. Entenderás que no es posible saber qué está fallando sin ver el código.

Comment: @Mariano, gracias por resopnder. Bueno en realidad, si te fijas en este ejemplo: http://codepen.io/tehsis/pen/AFCwz que es el que el creador del plugin, no estoy haciendo nada diferente, pero ahí funciona bien. Quizá influya el tamaño de la ruleta (aunque no debería, es un circulo).

Comment: Veo que tomaste uno de los ejemplos publicados por el autor... Asimismo, si te fijás el 3er ejemplo (http://codepen.io/asleepypenguin/pen/bebZBj) parecería estar funcionando mal.. Por eso mismo es que te recomiendo que contactes al autor del plugin. Quizás es sólo cuando se configura como *counter-clockwise*, pero no lo sé.

Comment: Bueno, si te refieres a que siempre es seleccionada la misma opción, es porque el método spin() recibe un entero, este entero es para que siempre se seleccione la opción correspondiente a ese indice. Si se deja sin parámetros, queda aleatorio.

Comment: Si, parece tener un pequeño offset.

Comment: Que tal, soy el autor del plugin. Hay dos cosas que faltan en tu código para que funcione como esperas. La primera: `options.prices` puede ser un array de prices, en este caso: `animals`. Tenes que asignar a prices ese array. Lo segundo, es que para que caiga siempre en la misma opción, tenes que pasarselo como parametro a `.spin` (en este caso, el indice del array). De otra forma, va a hacer un random entre todos los posibles `prices`.
Te dejo un codepen con esto funcionando: https://codepen.io/tehsis/pen/GjBxYd

Comment: Lo que faltaria, para que funcione correctamente, es que matchees el orden del array de `prices` con las pocisiones de la imagen de la ruleta.

Comment: Hola tehsis, gracias por tu ayuda. En realidad el problema no es con eso, que se que debe ir así. El problema es con en que ubicación -grados- cae la opción seleccionada en la ruleta, si te fijas, la aguja no apunta a la opción que cae. La ruleta esta emparejada con el array "animals", mismo orden, mismos elementos, son 360, deberían ser 10 grados cada uno.

Comment: Lo que digo es que la rotación parece no mantenerse igual para todos los giros -spins-, pues suponiendo que cae el 36 en el grado 90 y luego vuelve a caer el 36, esta segunda vez no esta en el grado 90.

Comment: Perfecto, ya entendí el problema. Es un bug con el offset que tiene cada posición.
Intentare solucionarlo en unas horas. Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias tehsis.